# Sorting posts by specific order

Tags: get-posts, sort

I have a custom post type and I want to be able to control the order that the posts are displayed by defining the order in an array, and then checking the posts meta_value against the array to see where it should sit in the order of posts.

Using the code below I can get the dealers who's 'Postcode' is one of the values defined in the $target_postcodes array of the 10 closest postcodes to the current users location.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'dealer',
        'meta_key' => 'Postcode',
        'meta_value' => $target_postcodes,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));
```

Is it possible for me to sort the posts by the order of the values in the 'meta_values' query?

For example, if we use the following post values:

```
[Name]    [Postcode]
Dealer 1  1234
Dealer 2  2345
Dealer 3  3456
Dealer 4  4567
```

And then the define the $target_postcodes array as

```
$target_postcodes = 4567,1234,3456,2345
```

I would then want the loop to display the dealers in the following order

```
Dealer 4
Dealer 1
Dealer 3
Dealer 2
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up querying each postcode separately then compiling the results into the $posts[] array using array_merge. This meant that the final $posts[] array contained all my posts in distance order and I could loop through it normally.

I understand this is a really inneficient way of doing it and would appreciate if anyone could give some feedback/improvements!

The code was similar to below:

```
/** My array of postcodes, from closest to farthest**/
$postcodes[1111,2222,3333,4444,5555];

/**
 Loop through each postcode and grab all the dealers 
where the postcode matches the one in that loop
**/
foreach($postcodes as $the_postcode){
    $subSet = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'dealer',
        'meta_key' => 'Postcode',
        'meta_value' => $the_postcode,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));
    /**
    Append the new results to the the end of the $posts array
    **/
    $posts = array_merge($posts,$currentSet);
}

/** Display final list of post titles in the order of values defined in $postcodes**/
if($posts)
{ 
    foreach($posts as $post)
    {
    echo the_title().'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `meta_query` with relation `OR` instead of `meta_key` might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a custom query to achieve this. This [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query#Query_based_on_Custom_Field_and_Sorted_by_Value) example might be of use.

Comment: The problem is that we don't want to sort the dealers asc/desc by the $target_postcodes values, we want the system to sort the posts as per the position in the $target_postcodes array.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of how I want the data sorted

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is to accept another meta value along with the postal code that captures the distance and then use that to sort the posts. If you want to do it using the `target_postcodes` array - I think you need to do it programmatically. In that case, you may not be able to use the pagination provide by WP and the solution becomes more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The order of the $target_postcodes array changes depending on the postcode of the user who's viewing the page (so they are ordered closests > farthest) and the distance can't be stored in the database as it will be different depending on the users postcode, and I don't want to store the distance values for every single postcode combination :(

Comment: May be you can save the longitude&latitude for each postal code and then calculate the distance from the user's postal code. You might be even use this in the order by clause of the query and still use get_posts.

Comment: Yeah i'm already doing that to sort the nearest 10 postcodes by closest to farthest to create the $target_postcodes array, I just don't know how to make it so that the posts are sorted according to the order of the postcodes in the array. An ineffecient way of doing it would be to loop through the $target_postcodes array from closest to farthest, then do a loop using that postcode as the 'meta_value' parameter.